# Changing a PageModel property without using handler in Razor Pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm developing a web application using Asp.Net Core Razor Pages.On the page model I have the following property:

```
    public class SchoolModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public School SchoolEdit { get; set; }
```

I'd like to change the Logo property of SchoolEdit(of type School) when I click a button on the form without having the form posted.How can I accomplish this?
Here's the razor page code:

```
@if (Model.SchoolEdit.Logo != null)
   {
      <button class="btn btn-danger" asp-page-handler="RemovePhoto">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>                      
   }
```

Later,I defined the following Ajax to change the property when the button is clicked,but the OnPostRemovePhoto doesn't get hit!

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Click").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./School?handler=RemovePhoto",
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('hi');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the same thread on Asp.Net,I figured out the issue.
The anti-forgery token was missing.The AJAX method below sets the token in the header.
[Here's the answer:](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152512.aspx?Changing%20a%20PageModel%20property%20without%20using%20handler%20in%20Razor%20Pages)